# ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS               NAMES
fac6da40e9dc        hello-world           "/hello"                 2 hours ago         Exited (0) 2 hours ago                        nervous_merkle
04dc148ec933        9d418bac6a03          "/bin/sh -c 'apt-get…"   3 days ago          Exited (100) 3 days ago                       wonderful_dewdney
ad04a161f30d        gliderlabs/logspout   "/bin/logspout"          4 weeks ago

Answer (score 0):

Change the tag from latest to x86_64-1.0.2 in the compose file. There is no latest tag for this image. You can get all available tags on below link

https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-peer/tags/

Answer (score 0):

first Execute this command

```
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.4
```

Next Execute this command

```
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.4 hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
```